# How to perform cell validation in #ag-grid for Angular 4

Tags: ag-grid-ng2

I have started using ag-grid in my Angular 4 project, and was unable to find any API's for performing in-line cell validations i.e. whenever user edits a particular cell, the requirement is to perform a required field and pattern validation. In case of any validation errors, the corresponding editable field should get highlighted and an error message needs to be displayed.

I have used the following cell events to fulfill the above purpose, but none of them provided me the desired result.

- cellEditingStarted
- cellEditingStopped

Comment: Did you look at the ag-grid documentation? This page was helpful to me: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/. And the example here was useful: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-cell-editing (note: make sure to change the "Example Version" dropbox to "Angular").